# Is it possible to retrieve a list of all addresses within a certain region in Google Maps API?

Tags: api, google-maps, street-address

Say I want to retrieve a list of all addresses of Rome.

How do I achieve this programmatically in Google Maps API, or any other web service? I don't want the actual location of the addresses, just a list of the names of the addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that with the Google Maps API.

You can do [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) (both on the server-side or on the client-side), but with reverse geocoding you pass one coordinate and you are returned the address of that point only. The Google Maps API does not return all the addresses of a particular area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I guess this is the only solution. One needs to obtain the range of coordinates that correspond to the limits of this region. Then reverse geocode in this range with a certain step. However, too small of a step and it will take forever (due to usage limits), too large and it wont get all addresses.

Comment: @Zack: Yes, in theory that's one solution. However, as you said, you'll probably bump into the usage limits pretty quickly. You could also violate the [terms of use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html). You may find some other service that provides this information for the localities that you are interested in, but I don't really see the Google Maps API suitable for this purpose.